# Delphi XE5 cannot load VirtualTreeView components

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, virtualtreeview

I'm using Delphi XE5 and many years I'm using VirtualTreeView components. Now Delphi XE cannot load them. This messages appears:

> The procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\Bpl\VirtualTreesD19.bpl

and

> Can't load package C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\Bpl\VirtualTreesD19.bpl. The specific procedure could not be found.

I uninstall VirtualTreeView from Delphi and tried new instalation, but this not worked. Now I'm without VirtualTreeView.

I did no changes in Delphi settings and no install of anything, etc.
This situation appears after Windows 10 updates, but I don't know if it's causes my problem.

Can someone help me with this situation? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using this one : https://github.com/TurboPack/VirtualTreeView

Comment: @fpiette - No, I'm using older version due to compatibility with other developers and Delphi XE5. I think the current version of VirtualTreeView doesn't support my version of Delphi. My version of VirtualTreeView worked fine until Windows 10 was updated this week.

Comment: Maybe you could try to compile the [current version](https://github.com/TurboPack/VirtualTreeView) of VirtualTreeView ?

Comment: @fpiette - I'd like but I'm dependent on other developers and project owner. Many people means long discussion :-(
We are currently working on an upgrade to Delphi 11, but I've to work with current version before completing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found out solutions of my problem: The packages VirtualTrees*.bpl are build into standard folder for packages, eg. `C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\Bpl` or `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Bpl`. This folders are in system variable "Path" too. The paths of newest version od Delphi are before paths of older version.

I used the same version of VirtualTree, of course in separete folders by version of Delphi, name of built packages are the same and they are in separate folders (see above). But if I check loaded packages, I found that Delphi XE5 had loaded package from path of Delphi 11. Because older version of Delphi cannot works with packages that are built in newer version, I got my excepsion. I don't why Delphi works with packages by this methode, but when I set other path for built package, e.g. `.\..\build`, then everythink work correctly.